# Calculation of string in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column which contains a string like
`1.000*2.000*5.000`

Are there any way to get it evaluated and return the result in a new column?

Comment: is it just multiplication, or mixed operations?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is with a Javascript function:

```
create or replace function multiply(s string)
returns float 
language javascript
as 
'
var numbers = S.split("*");
var total = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    total *= parseFloat(numbers[i]);
}
return total;
';
```

Then:

```
select multiply('1.000*2.000*5.000');
```

Gives me:

```
10
```

Of course, using floats that in a form of 1.001 shows a float result:

```
select multiply('1.001*2.000*5.000');
```

gives me:

```
10.01
```